# Getting DNS Records from an Active Directory zone by IP Addresses

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory, zone

I am trying to run the following query against my DNS zone to return records based on the IP addresses and having no luck, the script runs but just empty output.

```
Get-Content ip.txt| ForEach {
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename "xxx.global" | where-object {$_.RecordData.ipv4address -eq "$_"}
}
```

The contents of the ip.txt file is like this:

```
"10.32.84.102"
"172.31.65.18"
"172.31.65.203"
```

I tried modifying my original command which works fine, but I want to run it against a list of IPs..

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename "xxx.global" | where-object {$_.RecordData.ipv4address -eq "10.32.84.102"}
```

[image: Single line command works fine]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `$_` to refer to different objects in your `Where-Object`.

```
where-object {$_.RecordData.ipv4address -eq "$_"}
             ^^^^                           ^^^^
```

`$_` is only set to one object at a time. If you start another pipeline, the previous value is going to be gone.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
$IPs = Get-Content ip.txt

foreach ($IP in $IPs) {
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename "xxx.global" | where-object { $_.RecordData.ipv4address -eq $IP }
}
```

You may also need to remove the double quotes from ip.txt. The IP is `10.32.84.102`, not `"10.32.84.102"`.